# I cannot find emplace_back function .How can i get and use this function if possible help anyone

Tags: c++

I cannot find the emplace_back function[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlg3f.png). How can I get and use this function if possible help anyone?

I cannot find emplace_back function .How can i get and use this function if possible help anyone.

Comment: Did you set the C++ standard used to at least C++11? Also note that 17.12 came out in 2017. C++ has received three new versions since then.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: `vector<int> max[N]` why not std::vector<std::vector<int>> max(N)` to be consistent? And not mix C++ (dynamic) arrays with "C" style arrays? Also since this is C++ you should not use `#define` anymore for your constants. e.g. use `static constexpr std::size_t Max{1000};`. At least then Max will have a type (std::size_t)

Comment: Also next time make your code part of the question. Copy it into your question, select it and press ctrl+k to format it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see this: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: This means your compiler is more than a decade out of date. You may want to uninstall it and replace it with a more modern compiler. You can still use the same IDE.

Comment: [Instructions for getting a best of breed, that'll easily work with Code::Blocks on Windows at any rate, toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/4581301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a newer version 20.03 of CodeBlocks available. There  is not reason to use this version.
2. You need to a setting to the compiler to support newer versions of C++ language.  Go to **Setting**->**Compiler** and select `-std=c++11` or a newer one like `-std=c++20`.